# How to let app users execute arbitrary SELECT statements securely?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

I would like to let the users of an application to execute arbitrary `SELECT` statements and only `SELECT` statements on the app's database by entering the query in a textbox.

Which keywords must be filtered out to keep things secure and what other security aspect should be taken into consideration?

This is what I have already figured out:

- filter out queries starting with: `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`
- split the user's input at semicolon and pass through the filter all individual statements

There is anything else to check?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't trust yourself when parsing SQL queries. For example, you could write a query like `exec ('drop database sc3w');`. Instead, run the user queries using a read-only database account.

Comment: Can't you use permissions on your sql engine?

Comment: @David Brabant Unfortunately I can't use permissions, I have to solve this  at the app level

Comment: It's possible to do some deeply unsettling things to a database with just `SELECT` permissions and malicious intentions (such as a query that takes inordinate amounts of time to process and takes locks on every table).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, don't. It doesn't matter how good you think you've been with your SQL parsing code, someone, sooner or later, whether malicious or not, will find something you haven't covered. The only *secure* way to do this is via SQL Server permissions. Even then it's not necessarily a good idea because someone can easily write SQL that locks the database up.

Can you review your requirement and see whether users really need to be able to execute arbitrary queries. More likely there are certain things that they want to know on an adhoc basis, in which case you could provide canned queries that are executed on a button click, potentially parameterised. If they really must be able to execute arbitrary queries then can they do it on a copy of the real database, i.e. every night backup the real one and restore it to a place where the users can do whatever they want without causing much damage?

As a last resort, and this isn't a recommendation, just an observation from experience, email your boss saying it's not safe and a user could easily bring the system down, but as long as your boss confirms in writing that they'll take responsibility then you're happy to do it.

Comment: Disagree that this is impossible, since stackoverflow exposes SELECT to the open internet: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new